# How to disable CSP protection in chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, security

**What am I doing ?**

I wrote a script that runs every 1 second and sends a POST request with some data to a server which is running locally. Since the page that I am trying this on has some response headers attached to it (CSP headers). Therefore, the request is unable to proceed to CSP policy in chrome.

Here is the error I get

> Refused to connect to 'https://domain.in/api/users' because it
>   violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "connect-src
>   'self' https://*.whatsapp.net https://www.facebook.com
>   https://*.giphy.com https://*.tenor.co blob:
>   https://crashlogs.whatsapp.net/wa_clb_data
>   https://crashlogs.whatsapp.net/wa_fls_upload_check
>   https://www.bingapis.com/api/v6/images/search
>   https://*.google-analytics.com wss://*.web.whatsapp.com
>   wss://web.whatsapp.com https://dyn.web.whatsapp.com"

**What I want ?**

Since I am just testing few things, I can bear an insecure environment by disabling the CSP in chrome. So please tell me how to do that ?

**What have I tried/read so far ?**
I have tried searching for this online and even some of the questions on SO but none of them gave a satisfying and completely working example. Some have suggested using this plugin but I can't see it working in my case.

Please suggest all that you can.

Comment: Can you simply update the CSP to allow this connection?

Comment: Also if you are the owner of the API website that is very badly set up; there is no security so I can download and view all parts of that API data. `:-(`

Comment: I am using chrome tools with web.whatsapp.com opened in the same tab. I just want to test something with CSP disabled so the browser allows me to send the requests.

Comment: @Martin yeah I tried updating the CSP to allow me that but that still didn't work. I am sure I am missing something really small here or the support for disabling CSP just vanished overnight :0

Comment: Apparently the enable CSP plugin requires you to turn it on before the website loads. Now its working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the Disable CSP plugin actually works but it fails sometimes. This may be because the server sends the CSP header as soon as the connection between the client and server completes. I needed to toggle this plugin just before that for it to work.

That is how I got it working.